# Using LRU Cache with python's Gunicorn

Tags: python, gunicorn, lru

Trying to put data into LruCache and then get it back. I am using postman to get the data via api, every fourth or fifth time I retry the api, data is returned form the cache. Whereas for first tries, it takes time and never returns from the cache. I think data is not being cached in the first placed. Please help, what might be the issue here with python's LRU Cache and Gunicorn

I am expecting data to be returned via cache, 2nd time I hit my api. But actually data is retuned from cache, after several tries of hitting the api.

Comment: Please, provide [mre]. What makes you think the respective function is actually called again? What did you do to debug, e.g. adding some debug logs/prints that prove the function runs again?

Comment: Due to multiple workers with gunicorn, every worker tends to have its own cache. Therefore if api is served by any worker that hasnt cached any data into it, will repeat the whole process of data fetching again. Redis can be a cure for this.